# IP payload compression with xfrm

Tags: linux, networking, ip, compression

I'm trying to compress IP payload with `ip xfrm` between 2 computers. Computer 1 has the IP address `192.168.0.1` and computer 2 has `192.168.0.2`. I successfully established a IPSec link between the 2 machines following [this gist](https://gist.github.com/vishvananda/7094676). I tried to adapt it for the compression. I ran the following command :

Computer 1

```
sudo ip xfrm state add src 192.168.0.1 dst 192.168.0.2 proto comp comp deflate
sudo ip xfrm policy add src 192.168.0.1 dst 192.168.0.2 dir out tmpl proto comp
```

Computer 2

```
sudo ip xfrm state add src 192.168.0.1 dst 192.168.0.2 proto comp comp deflate
sudo ip xfrm policy add src 192.168.0.1 dst 192.168.0.2 dir in tmpl proto comp
```

I first test it by pinging C2 with C1 and I'm capturing the traffic between with Wireshark. The PING is working in only 1 way : just the request is sent (`no respond found` displayed on C2 and no reply sent) and on Wireshark I'm not seeing any compression in any direction. I interpreted that as the payload is too small so `xfrm` doesn't compress the packet.
Then I tried to established a `SSH` connection from C1 to C2. `SSH` is working fine without compression enabled. When I enable the compression, Wireshark shows compressed packets, but the SSH client is waiting endlessly (same reason as PING) and end up with a `connection timed out`. I think this is because M2 doesn't decompress the IP packages, packages can't be read and are dropped.

I know that those rules are not bidirectional and are only for an "upload" direction. So I also tried by completing with the rules for download : switching IPs and `dir` policy. It's end up with the same results.

**My questions are :** Where am I wrong ? Which is the good way to use `xfrm` to have compression and get working the 'download' link ?

Ps : I'm quite new and the lack of explanation made `xfrm` quite difficult to understand how to properly use it and how it's working. So my interpretation earlier my be wrong.

Comment: Note that it's pointless to apply compression to encrypted traffic, because encrypted data is generally indistinguishable from random data (very high entropy). Better use the compression feature within SSH itself.

Comment: Ssh is only for a testing purposes here. I also know that compressing a picture directly instead of doing on each ip payload would me more effective. I'm doing it with xfrm more or less by curiosity / for knowledge.

Comment: Does anything in https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IPComp help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is improper:

PC2

```
sudo ip xfrm policy add src 192.168.0.1 dst 192.168.0.2 dir in tmpl proto comp
```

It causes PC2 blocking packets from PC1 that are not compressed (due to small packet size).

In the following configs, `ping -s1000 192.168.0.2` from PC1 may succeed, while `ping -s56 192.168.0.2` gets no response:

PC1

```
sudo ip xfrm policy add src 192.168.0.1 dst 192.168.0.2 dir out tmpl proto comp mode transport
sudo ip xfrm state add src 192.168.0.1 dst 192.168.0.2 proto comp spi 2 comp deflate mode transport
sudo ip xfrm policy add src 192.168.0.2 dst 192.168.0.1 dir in tmpl proto comp mode transport
sudo ip xfrm state add src 192.168.0.2 dst 192.168.0.1 proto comp spi 2 comp deflate mode transport
```

PC2

```
sudo ip xfrm policy add src 192.168.0.1 dst 192.168.0.2 dir in tmpl proto comp mode transport
sudo ip xfrm state add src 192.168.0.1 dst 192.168.0.2 proto comp spi 2 comp deflate mode transport
sudo ip xfrm policy add src 192.168.0.2 dst 192.168.0.1 dir out tmpl proto comp mode transport
sudo ip xfrm state add src 192.168.0.2 dst 192.168.0.1 proto comp spi 2 comp deflate mode transport
```

By removing those lines that contain "xfrm policy add .* dir in tmpl proto comp", `ping -s56 192.168.0.2` from PC1 succeeds, as well as other connections such as SSH. As a result:

PC1

```
sudo ip xfrm policy add src 192.168.0.1 dst 192.168.0.2 dir out tmpl proto comp mode transport
sudo ip xfrm state add src 192.168.0.1 dst 192.168.0.2 proto comp spi 2 comp deflate mode transport
sudo ip xfrm state add src 192.168.0.2 dst 192.168.0.1 proto comp spi 2 comp deflate mode transport
```

PC2

```
sudo ip xfrm state add src 192.168.0.1 dst 192.168.0.2 proto comp spi 2 comp deflate mode transport
sudo ip xfrm policy add src 192.168.0.2 dst 192.168.0.1 dir out tmpl proto comp mode transport
sudo ip xfrm state add src 192.168.0.2 dst 192.168.0.1 proto comp spi 2 comp deflate mode transport
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace "192.168.0.1" by "192.168.0.2" and vice versa in your "Computer 2" setup.